# Redirect after submitting custom entity form

Tags: 8, entities

I'm working with a custom entity and would like to programmatically set the redirect based on submitted values.

When I set the redirect path however, the user is redirected to the canonical path instead of the path I'm setting in the redirect.

In the file `mymodule/src/Form/MyEntityForm.php`, I'm doing something like this:

```
  public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
  {
    // Note: Same results with the order of the next 2 lines reversed.
    parent::submitForm($form, $form_state);
    $form_state->setRedirect('mymodule.overview', ['state' => 'CA']);
  }
```

So how would I set the destination of an entity form submission dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you need to override [EntityFormInterface::save()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21EntityFormInterface.php/function/EntityFormInterface%3A%3Asave/8.4.x):

> Form submission handler for the 'save' action.
>
> Normally this method should be overridden to provide specific messages
>   to the user and redirect the form after the entity has been saved.

`submitForm()` is the first submit handler called and should not be used to override submit actions.